# Getting the top 50 numbers from a hash table with chaining collision resolution

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, hashtable

I have an array of nodes in the hash table and every node has a pointer to a next pointer in case there is collision. Now I'm trying to get the top 50 elements with highest count. using priority queue using linked list. Since I already have a "next" pointer for the array of nodes, will making a second next for the priority queue the best option? (Setting next in the priority queue will change the next in the array of nodes as well!). How about implementing the priority queue with array? (but requires lot of shifting). What are the best approaches to this?

```
class Node
{
public:
    //to store the word
    string word;

    //number of occurences
    int count;

    //pointer to hold the next address
    Node* next;
};
```

Comment: The program requires it to use hash to extract words from a book. After that execution, I will have to display to 50 most occuring words. I agree with wrong data structure as in using the priority queue implemented by linked list.

Comment: I mistook the problem — which is why I've deleted the comment.  How many words are you dealing with? A few hundred? A few thousand?  I haven't thought it through, but I'd be inclined to create an array with 50 entries. Iterate through the hash table...while there's space in the array, add the hash entry in the correct place (maybe a heap rather than a fully sorted array). When there isn't space, if the new count is too small, ignore it; when it is big enough to fit, insert it into the heap after evicting the smallest count (so insert the new value in place of the smallest, and then sift up).

Comment: Thanks. This should work.

Comment: Your `next` hashtable pointer will point to a totally unrelated number. It is useless for the problem at hand. You can implement a priority queue with a standard C++ class called `std::priority_queue`.